# node.js with Azure Storage TableQuery where colName like

Tags: node.js, azure-sql-reporting

I am using node.js with Azure sql. I am trying to do a simple search.
I keep getting, "InvalidInput" : "One of the request inputs is not valid.".

```
function getItems(callback){
   var query = azure.TableQuery
     .select()
     .from('Employee')
     .where(['Email like ?', 'test%']);

  tableService.queryEntities(query, function(error, items){
    if(error == null){
       callback(items);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try url encoding the percent symbol; replace 'test%' with 'test%25'